# Помогите разобраться со статьей для установке php+mysql+composer

Tags: docker

Не могу никак ддогнать, впервый раз использую docker потому что пересел на linux debian 9 GNU и у меня немножко стало непонятно некоторые вещи
Смотрю я статью https://phptoday.ru/post/gotovim-lokalnuyu-sredu-docker-dlya-razrabotki-na-php
Сказано

> для этого откроем браузер и перейдем по адресу http://hello.dev/, но
>   сперва добавим одну строку в hosts файл.
>   127.0.0.1 hello.dev
>   Я все установил и у меня выходит

```
docker_mysql_1 is up-to-date
docker_php_1 is up-to-date
Starting docker_nginx_1 ... done
```

Добавил в /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtaulHost *:81>
        DocumentRoot /home/ruslan/Разработка/docker/www/hello.dev
        ServerName www.hello.dev
        ServerAlias hello.dev
        <Directory /home/ruslan/Разработка/docker/www/hello.dev>
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

В /etc/hosts

```
127.0.1.2       hello.dev
```

Полная настройка docker тут https://github.com/rusline18/docker-phpSever
Я только скажу, что nginx я указад ports: 81:81
Но почему-то hello.dev выходит страница  Apache2 Debian Default Page А на странице hello.dev:81 то пишет сервер не найден. Как быть

Comment: Вам совершенно точно вообще в принципе не нужно трогать апач. Сейчас он у вас занимает порт 81 и предотвращает запуск nginx на том же порту.

Comment: Не совсем понял @etki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

Не нужно было менять `80:80` на `81:81`. Нужно было менять на `81:80`.
Первая цифра - это порт на **хостовой** машине, на котором нужно принимать подключения - его вы можете задавать **любым**.

Вторая цифра - порт процесса внутри контейнера на который перенаправлять подключения. **Его задает автор образа при создании.**

Делать запись в `/etc/hosts` тоже не имеет большого смысла. Есть отличный сервис **xio.io**: допустим, локальный адрес вашей машины **192.168.1.1**. Тогда без каких либо модификаций, вы можете использовать адреса в домене **192.168.1.1.xip.io**. Например http://hello.dev.192.168.1.1.xip.io

Соответственно в веб-сервере нужно прописывать домен не **hello.dev**, а **hello.dev.192.168.1.1.xip.io**, зато никаких правок в *hosts* и будет работать на вех компьютерах в локальной сети.

**В вопросе есть еще одна проблема**: пытаясь решить конфликт на 80 порту, вы перенесли на 81 и nginx в контейнере, и локальный apache2. Об этом говорил @etki